# How to create a separate window for terminal in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can only create a terminal below or at the right side of the current windows, how can I move my terminal to a new window.

Comment: `File`-`New Window`,open a new terminal in new window

Comment: Instead of creating a separate VSCode's terminal window, why don't you just simply open a Windows Powershell/CMD or Linux Terminal ?

edited: If you want to do that to run VSCode Tasks then I think open another VSCode window is the only way...

Comment: Answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68247892/836330

Comment: That answer is pretty wordy, here is a TL;DR 
File -> Duplicate Workspace -> Terminal -> Expand terminal ... ta da!

Answer (score -2):

If terminal below or right is bothering you, and you say you want the terminal in a new window, wouldn't it be great if you just open your terminal in the next window?
VS Code in one window and iTerm in the second window with directory set to you code path.

Comment: Just wondering if there is a shortcut and maybe I just need to manually open a new window. Plus, do you know how to create a new window for debugging in VScode?