# Move terminal in Visual Studio Code to another screen (or the to a new editor tab)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

would you know if it is possible to open the terminal of visual studio code in window to put it on a second screen? thank you

Answer (score 5):

In the next version of vscode, v1.58, you will be able to drag or move a terminal to an editor.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#terminals-in-the-editor-area

And in v1.59 you will be able to drag a terminal to another window.

> Drag terminals from the tabs list or editor area of one window into
> the tabs list, editor area, or panel of another window.

[image: terminal drag and drop]

---

> Terminals in the editor area
>
> Terminals can now be created in or moved to the editor area, enabling
> a multi-dimensional grid layout that persists and remains visible
> regardless of panel state.
>
> Create terminals via the Create Terminal in Editor Area command.
>
> Move a terminal from the panel to the editor by dragging and dropping
> from the tabs list, running Move Terminal into Editor Area with a
> terminal focused, or selecting the context menu action.

So in the Insiders Build now I can open a new window and drag a terminal from there previous window to the new window easily (as a **terminal editor** now) or simply into its own editor in the same window.

[image: moving terminals to new window or editor area]

Note that moving an existing editor to a new window apparently changes the working directory so if you want the old cwd you will have to cd to it.  Moving an terminal into the same window's editor area preserves all of its state.

Comment: Does not work in VSCode version 1.76.0 (for 'Terminal' or 'Jupyter: Variables'. The mouse pointer just switches to a red 'Unavailable' icon when you click and drag to the editor section or the interactive window.

Comment: The dumb workaround: as of now (1.85.1) if you only have ONE shell open, you need to click into the Terminal tab in VSCode and then click the name of the shell session (typically on the right) and either click and drag it into the editor area OR click and choose "Move Terminal into Editor Area" in the menu that pops up and THEN you can drag out the tab to a new window (or another window). This seems to preserve the working directory as well. If you just open a second shell session you can drag either of them out to a new window directly which seems like horrible UX.

Comment: See also Mark's excellent demo elsewhere, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77233318/3794873

Answer (score -2):

I do not think it is possible to open the integrated terminal in a new window directly. why don't you use separate terminal.

Comment: This answer is quite vague; please provide instructions.

Comment: Typically I use the built-in terminal for running testing commands that I do NOT want polluting my shell history in Powershell or Windows Terminal or WSL or whatever, so an external terminal isn't the answer.